# ProgrammingError after reverting migration after AttributeError

Tags: django, wagtail

I did the migration after adding SourceBook and SourceBooksOrderable and that worked. Then I managed to add two snippets in wagtail admin. But when I tried to add them into the BlogPage in admin, I got an AttributeError.

Thinking that it was somehow a problem with the migration, I reverted migrations using `python manage.py migrate blog 0001`. Now I get a ProgrammingError under the snippet in admin.

Tracebacks, models.py and migration files are below. How can I fix this?

blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase
from wagtail.core.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.core import blocks
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel, MultiFieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.images.blocks import ImageChooserBlock
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel


richtext_features = [
    'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 
    "ol", "ul", "hr", 
    "link", "document-link", 
    "image", "embed",
    "code", "blockquote",
    "superscript", "subscript", "strikethrough",
]


class BlogListingPage(Page):
    """Listing page lists all the Blog pages."""

    template = "blog/blog_listing_page.html"
    subpage_types = ['blog.BlogPage']

    custom_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Overwrites the default title',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("custom_title"),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Adding custom stuff to our context."""
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context["posts"] = BlogPage.objects.live().public().order_by('-date')

        if request.GET.get('tag', None):
            tags = request.GET.get('tag')
            all_posts = context["posts"].filter(tags__slug__in=[tags])

        return context

    class Meta:

        verbose_name = "Blog Listing Page"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Listing Pages"


@register_snippet
class BlogTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        'BlogPage',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Tag"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Tags"


class BlogPage(Page):
    """ For individual blog pages."""
        
    template = "blog/blog_page.html"
    parent_page_types = ['blog.BlogListingPage']
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogTag, blank=True)

    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Niq")
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    content = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(form_classname="full title")),
        ('standfirst', blocks.RichTextBlock(features=richtext_features)),
        ('main_content', blocks.RichTextBlock(features=richtext_features)),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ], block_counts={
        'heading': {'min_num': 1, 'max_num': 1,},
        'standfirst': {'max_num': 1,},
    })

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('author'),
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel("tags"),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                InlinePanel("source_books", label="Book")
            ],
            heading="Book(s)"
        ),
        StreamFieldPanel('content'),
    ]

    @property
    def heading(self):
        for block in self.content:
            if block.block_type == 'heading':
                return block.value

    @property
    def standfirst(self):
        for block in self.content:
            if block.block_type == 'standfirst':
                return block.value


    class Meta:

        verbose_name = "Blog Page"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Pages"


class SourceBooksOrderable(Orderable):
    """This allows us to select one or more blog authors from Snippets."""

    page = ParentalKey("blog.BlogPage", related_name="source_books")
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        "blog.SourceBook",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    panels = [
        SnippetChooserPanel("book"),
    ]


@register_snippet
class SourceBook(models.Model):

    title_and_author = models.CharField(max_length=500, help_text="E.g. Title ABC by Jane Doe, John Doe & Albert Einstein")
    link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Affiliate link")
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        related_name="+",
    )
    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("title_and_author"),
                ImageChooserPanel("image"),
            ],
            heading="Name and Image",
        ),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("link"),
            ],
            heading="Links"
        )
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        """String repr of this class."""
        return self.title_and_author

    class Meta:  # noqa
        verbose_name = "Source Book"
        verbose_name_plural = "Source Books"
```

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/pages/add/blog/blogpage/5/

Django Version: 3.2.4
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['home',
 'search',
 'userauth',
 'blog',
 'menus',
 'contact',
 'wagtail.contrib.forms',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
 'wagtail.embeds',
 'wagtail.sites',
 'wagtail.users',
 'wagtail.snippets',
 'wagtail.documents',
 'wagtail.images',
 'wagtail.search',
 'wagtail.admin',
 'wagtail.core',
 'modelcluster',
 'taggit',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'django_extensions',
 'captcha',
 'wagtailcaptcha',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'debug_toolbar']
Installed Middleware:
['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py", line 108, in wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/auth.py", line 172, in decorated_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages/create.py", line 99, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages/create.py", line 107, in post
    return self.form_valid(self.form)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages/create.py", line 117, in form_valid
    return self.save_action()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages/create.py", line 135, in save_action
    self.parent_page.add_child(instance=self.page)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/treebeard/mp_tree.py", line 1083, in add_child
    return MP_AddChildHandler(self, **kwargs).process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/treebeard/mp_tree.py", line 377, in process
    newobj.path = self.node.get_last_child()._inc_path()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/pages/add/blog/blogpage/5/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inc_path'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "blog_sourcebook" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "blog_sourcebook"
                                          ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py", line 108, in wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/auth.py", line 172, in decorated_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/snippets/views/snippets.py", line 133, in list
    paginated_items = paginator.get_page(request.GET.get('p'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 72, in get_page
    return self.page(number)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 76, in page
    number = self.validate_number(number)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 54, in validate_number
    if number > self.num_pages:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 103, in num_pages
    if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 97, in count
    return c()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 412, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 517, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 502, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 198, in execute
    return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 133, in _record
    return method(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/snippets/blog/sourcebook/
Exception Value: relation "blog_sourcebook" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "blog_sourcebook"
                                          ^
```

blog\migrations\0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.4 on 2021-06-20 01:54

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import modelcluster.contrib.taggit
import modelcluster.fields
import wagtail.core.blocks
import wagtail.core.fields
import wagtail.images.blocks


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('wagtailcore', '0062_comment_models_and_pagesubscription'),
        ('taggit', '0003_taggeditem_add_unique_index'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BlogListingPage',
            fields=[
                ('page_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='wagtailcore.page')),
                ('custom_title', models.CharField(help_text='Overwrites the default title', max_length=255)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Blog Listing Page',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Blog Listing Pages',
            },
            bases=('wagtailcore.page',),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BlogPage',
            fields=[
                ('page_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='wagtailcore.page')),
                ('author', models.CharField(default='Niq', max_length=255)),
                ('date', models.DateField(verbose_name='Post date')),
                ('content', wagtail.core.fields.StreamField([('heading', wagtail.core.blocks.CharBlock(form_classname='full title')), ('standfirst', wagtail.core.blocks.RichTextBlock(features=['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'ol', 'ul', 'hr', 'link', 'document-link', 'image', 'embed', 'code', 'blockquote', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'strikethrough'])), ('main_content', wagtail.core.blocks.RichTextBlock(features=['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'ol', 'ul', 'hr', 'link', 'document-link', 'image', 'embed', 'code', 'blockquote', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'strikethrough'])), ('image', wagtail.images.blocks.ImageChooserBlock())])),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Blog Page',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Blog Pages',
            },
            bases=('wagtailcore.page',),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='BlogTag',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('content_object', modelcluster.fields.ParentalKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='blog.blogpage')),
                ('tag', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='blog_blogtag_items', to='taggit.tag')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Blog Tag',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Blog Tags',
            },
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='blogpage',
            name='tags',
            field=modelcluster.contrib.taggit.ClusterTaggableManager(blank=True, help_text='A comma-separated list of tags.', through='blog.BlogTag', to='taggit.Tag', verbose_name='Tags'),
        ),
    ]
```

blog\migrations\0002_sourcebook_sourcebooksorderable.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.4 on 2021-06-22 03:10

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import modelcluster.fields


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('wagtailimages', '0023_add_choose_permissions'),
        ('blog', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='SourceBook',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title_and_author', models.CharField(help_text='E.g. Title ABC by Jane Doe, John Doe & Albert Einstein', max_length=500)),
                ('link', models.URLField(blank=True, help_text='Affiliate link', null=True)),
                ('image', models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='+', to='wagtailimages.image')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Source Book',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Source Books',
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='SourceBooksOrderable',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('sort_order', models.IntegerField(blank=True, editable=False, null=True)),
                ('book', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='blog.sourcebook')),
                ('page', modelcluster.fields.ParentalKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='source_books', to='blog.blogpage')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['sort_order'],
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Running `python manage.py migrate` again

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, blog, contact, contenttypes, home, menus, sessions, sites, socialaccount, taggit, userauth, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Applying blog.0002_sourcebook_sourcebooksorderable... OK
```

AttributeError traceback after latest migration

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/urls/__init__.py", line 108, in wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/auth.py", line 172, in decorated_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages/create.py", line 99, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages/create.py", line 107, in post
    return self.form_valid(self.form)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages/create.py", line 113, in form_valid
    return self.publish_action()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/admin/views/pages/create.py", line 158, in publish_action
    self.parent_page.add_child(instance=self.page)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/treebeard/mp_tree.py", line 1083, in add_child
    return MP_AddChildHandler(self, **kwargs).process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/treebeard/mp_tree.py", line 377, in process
    newobj.path = self.node.get_last_child()._inc_path()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/pages/add/blog/blogpage/5/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inc_path'
```

Comment: Well _migrate_... i.e. run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I just tried that and got the AttributeError when trying to save the BlogPage. I pasted the traceback above. It looks the same as the previous. There is no longer an error when I tried to add a snippet.

Comment: Looks like somehow your tree is broken? Check these 2 similar issues on wagtail's GitHub: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5312 and https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3402